# Dealing with arrays and fit function in Gnuplot

Tags: curve-fitting, gnuplot

I want to evaluate the Birch-Murnaghan Equation of State (BM-EOS) for different volumes.
I tried declaring a 1D array `A` in which every element would be the answer of BM-EOS for different volumes.

```
B0P = 4; B0 = 30
V0 = 36; E0 = -535; R4  = -535
array A[400]
do for [i=1:400] {
A[i] = E0+(9/8*B0*V0)*((V0/((((i/100)**3)/100)**3))**(2/3)-1)**2\
         + 9/16*B0*(B0P-4)*V0*((V0/((i/100)**3))**(2/3)-1)**3\
         + R4*((V0/((i/100)**3))**(2/3)-1)**4
}
```

I am getting error as `undefined value`. Can anyone please tell what is wrong in this Gnuplot code?
Later I will use `stats` command on `A` to find the minimum value.
Also, is there any other better way to find out minima of a fit function in Gnuplot? This answer did not help much: [Gnuplot: How can I determine the maxima of a fit function in gnuplot?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32524/gnuplot-how-can-i-determine-the-maxima-of-a-fit-function-in-gnuplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put a dot in all the numbers which are supposed to be floats, so as to be correct while doing division. In gnuplot

2/3 = 0

but

2.0/3.0 = 0.66666..7

In your example, you are suffering from division by zero, but gnuplot does not give good error message.

Here is corrected version which runs without any error

```
B0P = 4.0; B0 = 30.0
V0 = 36.0; E0 = -535.0; R4  = -535.0
array A[400]
do for [i=1:400] {
   A[i] = E0+(9.0/8.0*B0*V0)*((V0/((((i/100.0)**3)/100.0)**3))**(2.0/3.0)-1.0)**2\
     + 9.0/16.0*B0*(B0P-4.0)*V0*((V0/((i/100.0)**3))**(2.0/3.0)-1.0)**3\
     + R4*((V0/((i/100.0)**3))**(2.0/3.0)-1.0)**4
}
```

I use Gnuplot daily and like it a lot for plotting. But it is not really designed for computations. Why dont you use python for this ?

Comment: I can use Python. Since I already had the code written for Gnuplot hence thought of modifying it. Now, I'll have to start from scratch in Python.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion did clear that error message. A new error has come up:
"Column number or datablock line expected" pointing towards "9.0/8.0"
Looks like I should python only for this.

Comment: It works if you add .0 as I did in my updated answer. If this works for you, please accept the answer so we can close this thread.